# MS Word Doc showing logo/watermark only in Finder preview

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I have a word doc where when you look at the file preview in the Finder window on a mac (osx), it shows the first page and on the upper right corner of the page, theres a Qlikview logo (im guessing Qlikview contributed to the creation of the document). However when you open the document itself, the logo is not there and the document is in the correct/desired formatting.

I've tried
-saving it as a new file
-saving it as a .doc instead of .docx
-converting to google doc then downloading as .docx but the formatting is affected
-changing security settings on MS Word to "remove personal information from this file upon saving"
-checking for water marks/settings
-copy/pasting entire doc onto a new doc and saving

and none of these got rid of the mark.

Anyone know how to fix this or get around it? Or how to disable doc preview for this file only? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem: http://superuser.com/questions/1122061/ms-word-removing-header-working-only-os-x-preview-mode  
how solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I found this page after having the same issue.  Solution:

Click into your header /footer.  Click > Different First Page.

The logo and header will come up from an old source.

Delete it, and then unselect Different First Page.

Problem solved!

Comment: You saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not proper answer using MS Word, but Works.
Open your Document with LibreOffice.org (I have Cent OS 7 in another machine), You will see the "watermark" select it and delete.